# struct in function and output in a file

Tags: c, struct, printf, malloc

Can you help me with passing elements of `struct` into a function (`void show_info_abt_bus`) for outputting my information? I don't understand how I should pass those elements.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct info_bus_{
    int number;
    int begin;
    int end;
    char* stations;
    int time_working;
}info_bus;

void input_data_abt_bus(info_bus **,int);
void show_info_abt_bus(info_bus *,int);
void my_free(info_bus **,int);



void input_data_abt_bus(info_bus **b,int n){

    int i;
    char buffer[128];


   if(!((*b)=(info_bus *)malloc(n*sizeof(info_bus)))){
    printf("Error memory\n");
    exit(0);
   }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("Input the number of a bus: \n");
    scanf("%d",&((*b)[i].number));
    printf("%d)Input when it starts to work: \n",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&((*b)[i].begin));

    printf("%d)Input when it  finishes to work: \n",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&((*b)[i].end));

        printf("%d)Input its stations: \n",i+1);
        scanf(" %127[^\n]%*c", buffer);
        (*b)[i].stations = (char*) malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
        strcpy((*b)[i].stations, buffer);
        getchar();

    printf("Input time working: \n");
    scanf("%d",&((*b)[i].time_working));
        }
}

void my_free(info_bus **b,int n){
    int i;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free((*b)[i]);
    }
    free(b);
}

int main()
{
    int i,n;
    printf("How many buses u have: \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    info_bus *b=NULL;
    input_data_abt_bus(&b,n);
    show_info_bus_abt_bus(b,n);
    my_free(b,n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what error you get from the compiler?

Comment: @xFighter   it just doesnt print

Comment: Use `viod show_info_abt_bus(info_bus *);` as function signature.

Comment: @xFighter and i didnt declare (`show_info_abt_bus`) in the main fuction. because i dont know what the right way of it

Comment: @bansi okay, but in `show_info_abt_bus` how should i declare my elements of functions (`int number;`
    `int begin;`
    `int end;`
    `char* stations;`)

Comment: You already did that in your structure definition. And correctly using it in your function. Just use viod `show_info_abt_bus(info_bus *b){ `

Comment: @bansi I'll try , i'll say to you

Comment: As you only want readonly access you can use `viod show_info_abt_bus(info_bus b){` and access items as `b.number` instesd of `b->number`

Comment: @bansi i dont why , but it doesnt print , i did so:` void show_info_abt_bus(info_bus *,int);`
` show_info_abt_bus(b,n);`
`void show_info_abt_bus(info_bus *b,int n)`

Comment: And why do you need loop `for(i=0;i<n;i++){` in both functions? It is going going to be unexpected behaviour also, an `n` is never initialized.

Comment: Also how are you calling `show_info_abt_bus`?

Comment: @bansi look, when the cansole asks a user input how many busses he has and he inputted( for example 10) , i think i need a loop for it. Or how i should do it? beecause i dont know how many he will input. 
concerning `show_info_abt_bus` callin it like `show_info_abt_bus(b,n);`

Comment: @bansi please, look at my question again, i tried to do free allocated memory, is it the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass structure object Pass by reference in function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct info_bus_{
    int number;
    int begin;
    int end;
    char* stations;
    int time_working;
}info_bus;

void input_data_abt_bus(info_bus **,int);
void show_info_abt_bus(info_bus *,int);

void show_info_bus_abt_bus(info_bus *b,int n){
 int i;
  for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("\n===============================================");
    printf("\n[%d].the number of a bus: %d",i+1,b[i].number);
    printf("\n[%d]. Begin at: %d am",i+1,b[i].begin);
    printf("\n[%d]. Finishes at: %d pm",i+1,b[i].end);
    printf("\n[%d]. Stations: %s",i+1,b[i].stations);
    printf("\n[%d]. Time working: %d",i+1,b[i].time_working);
    printf("\n===============================================\n");
    }
}

void input_data_abt_bus(info_bus **b,int n){

    int i;
    char buffer[128];


    (*b)=(info_bus *)malloc(n*sizeof(info_bus));

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("Input the number of a bus: \n");
    scanf("%d",&((*b)[i].number));
    printf("%d)Input when it starts to work: \n",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&((*b)[i].begin));

    printf("%d)Input when it  finishes to work: \n",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&((*b)[i].end));

        printf("%d)Input its stations: \n",i+1);
        scanf(" %127[^\n]%*c", buffer);
        (*b)[i].stations = (char*) malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
        strcpy((*b)[i].stations, buffer);
        getchar();

    printf("Input time working: \n");
    scanf("%d",&((*b)[i].time_working));
        }
}
void my_free(info_bus **b,int n)
{
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         free((*b)[i].stations);
     }
     free((*b));
     (*b)=NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int i,n;
    printf("How many buses u have: \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    info_bus *b=NULL;
    input_data_abt_bus(&b,n);

    show_info_bus_abt_bus(b,n);
    my_free(&b,n)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what if n not 2? or 10,20,25 and so on?

Comment: @Nikitax i used n=2 only for testing. you can pass any number.

Comment: but how should i declare `n` in my fuctions? it's like `void show_info_abt_bus(info_bus *,int);` and `void show_info_bus_abt_bus(info_bus *b, int n)` and `show_info_bus_abt_bus(b,n);`

Comment: When you are asking `How many buses u have` you can pass that to both functions and use that instead of hardcoded 2. Also don't forget to `free` allocated memory. ( sry Not easy to handle code from mobile)

Comment: @Nikitax i have modified the answer.

Comment: Just a `free` would be great.

Comment: @Sumit Gemini  thank you for helping,now i understand thoroughly for yourself ahah

Comment: @bansi `free` i should create a new fuction for it, am i right?

Comment: @Nikitax welcome, and yes bansi is also right, do free memory.

Comment: @Sumit Gemini please, the last time , look at my question, is it the right way to free?

Comment: @Nikitax i have added free function too in answer. you forgot to free memory which you allocated for struct member "stations" to check memory leak using valgrind command. valgrind --leak-check=full --tool=memcheck program_name

Comment: @Sumit Gemini oh, i see now. Okay, thank you one more time!you helped me A LOT!